# A problem with two uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

A man and a woman agree to meet at a certain
location about $\text{12:30}$. If the man arrives at
a time uniformly distributed between $\text{12:15}$ and
$\text{12:45}$, and if the woman independently arrives at
a time uniformly distributed between $\text{12:00}$ and $\text{13:00}$, find the probability that the first to arrive
waits no longer than $5$ minutes. What is the probability
that the man arrives first?

Surely I have problems to understand the limit of integration for the second part.

**(a)** Let $X$ be the time the man arrives and $Y$ the time the woman arrives (both in fractions of 1 hour)
We want the probability $P(|X-Y|\le\frac{1}{12})$

The probability densities for each variable are
$$f_x(t) = \begin{cases}2  &\frac{1}{4} \le t \le \frac{3}{4}\\
0  & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
and

$$f_y(t) = \begin{cases}1  &0 \le t \le 1\\
0  & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

The probability is given by
$$P(|X-Y|\le\frac{1}{12})=P(Y-\frac{1}{12}\le X \le Y+\frac{1}{12})=
\int_{s=\frac{1}{4}}^{s=\frac{3}{4}} \int_{y-\frac{1}{12}}^{y+\frac{1}{12}} f_x(t)\cdot f_y(t) dt~ds = \int_{s=\frac{1}{4}}^{s=\frac{3}{4}} \left(\int_{y-\frac{1}{12}}^{y+\frac{1}{12}} f_x(t)~dt\right)\,ds = \frac{1}{6}$$

**(b)** For the second part we have to calculate $P(X<Y)$ but I don't know what to do about the limits of integration. could someone help me?

I'm finding these kind of problems very difficult. Could you suggest me a strategy ?

Comment: One would not want to mess up with $X$ and $x$, $Y$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you simply asking for help with the second part?

We can think about it in the following way:

Can we compute the probability that $X$ is smaller than $t \in \mathbb{R}$? Can we compute the probability that $Y = t$? Then, we can solve the problem by conditioning.

$\mathbb{P}(X<Y) = \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(X<Y|Y=t)f_Y(t)dt = \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(X<t)dt$.

Now, split the last integral into the summation of integrals on sections on $[0,1/4), [1/4,3/4], (3/4,1]$. Can you solve it from here?

----------EDIT------------

So how do we determine $\mathbb{P}(X<t)$? We know that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[1/4,3/4]$; therefore, it can never be less than $1/4$ and must always be less than $3/4$. Hence, for $t<1/4$, $\mathbb{P}(X<t) = 0$, and for $t>3/4$, $\mathbb{P}(X<t) = 1$. Now, for $t\in [1/4,3/4]$, we have that $\mathbb{P}(X<t)$ follows the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a uniform distribution; hence,

$\mathbb{P}(X<t) = \frac{t-1/4}{3/4-1/4} = 2t-1/2$.

If you are unsure about the CDF of a uniform distribution, try to determine it by integration and by simple geometry.

Comment: what is it your final risult?

Comment: the final answer should be 1/2

Comment: Is this clear or do you need some more explicit detail? If it is sufficient, please upvote or mark as solved. Otherwise, feel free to ask for more detail.

Comment: From my calculation it is 1.are you sure that the first limits of integration are 0 and 1?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X<t) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1, & t>3/4\\ 
2t-1/2, &t\in [1/4,3/4] \\ 
0, &t<1/4 
\end{matrix}\right.$ Therefore we can split the integral into: $\int_0^1\mathbb{P}(X<t)dt = \int_{0}^{1/4} 0 dt + \int_{1/4}^{3/4}(2t-1/2)dt + \int_{3/4}^1 1 dt = 0 + 0.25 + 0.25$.

Comment: can you explain how you found $P(X<t)$?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer above with more detail.

Comment: please check what i've written here

$$F_x(t) = P(x<t)=\begin{cases}1  &\frac{3}{4} \le t \le 1\\
\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{t}f_x(t)dt  &\frac{1}{4} \le t \le \frac{3}{4}\\
0  & t<\frac{1}{4}. \end{cases}$$
where $$\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{t}f_x(t)dt  =\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{t} 2 dt=2*(t-\frac{1}{4})=2*t-\frac{1}{2}$$     is it right?

Comment: @Anne That looks good. I'd be careful about using lower-case $x$ for a random variable (that is typically used to represent a realization of a random variable) - the preferred notation would be $X$. Similarly, the use of $*$ is typically reserved for the convolution operator, so I'd avoid that as well. The actual math looks correct though.